# How does an JAX-RS 'endpoint' behave when making a request?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, jax-rs

There is something I am not sure I understand correctlty, therefore, I need help:)

I have seen this: [example](https://cwiki.apache.org/WINK/jax-rs-context-information.html),

```
@Path("/resource")
public class Resource {
    @Context
    private HttpHeaders headers;

    @GET
    public void get(@Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
       /* use headers or uriInfo variable here */
    }
}
```

Does this mean that for each request the class that is transformed to 'endpoint' creates a separate thread? Because, otherwise, the headers information would not be accurate...

Can you please indicate a (short:) ) resource, not JAX-WS specifications, where I can find info about this?

Comment: A new thread is not always created. But you are guarenteed that `get()` and `headers` are local to the HTTP request.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't think of a shorter and more direct resource than the [JAX-RS 1.1 spec itself](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html). It is clear about [what you are asking](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-520005):

> JAX-RS provides facilities for obtaining and processing information about the application deployment context and the context of **individual** requests. (...)
>
> Context is specific to a **particular** request  (...).

May I add for completeness: that context information is obtained through the `@Context` annotation. As of resources, the context information is only available to the ones annotated with `@Path` (also called *root resources*). Also, `@Context` can inject the following [context types](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-540005.2): `Application`, `UriInfo`, `HttpHeaders`, `Request`, `SecurityContext` and `Providers`.

And about the [lifecycle](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec3.html#x3-200003.1.1) (request/thread management):

> **3.1.1 Lifecycle and Environment**
>
> By default a **new** resource class **instance** is created **for each request**
> to that resource. First the **constructor is called,
> then any requested dependencies are injected** (context is one of those dependencies), then
> the appropriate method is invoked and finally the
> object is made available for garbage collection.
>
> An implementation MAY
> offer other resource class lifecycles, mechanisms for specifying these
> are outside the scope of this specification. E.g. an implementation
> based on an inversion-of-control framework may support all of the
> lifecycle options provided by that framework.

The conclusion is:

- Each request is, by default, handled by a different resource instance;
- The context is injected at request time (thus a different context per instance).

Each specific implementation may change this lifecycle a bit, but the principles should be maintained (a context specific to each request).

As you can see, also, the spec says nothing about thread management. Since most JAX-RS implementations are Servlet-based, we can assume with certain safety that the each request instance goes to a different thread - as servlet containers are thread per request.

Comment: I'm also wondering about this. I agree that each request is handled by a separate thread, but multiple threads often share the same class instances for efficiency. So, use of @Context would appear not to be thread-safe at all!

Comment: Alex, these shared class instances should be coded to be thread-safe, meaning, they should themselves synchronize access to critical resources within them.