# Is it not possible to share global variable changes in jax rs?

Tags: java, ajax, jax-rs

Having a small problem doing a shopping cart in JAX-RS.

Im trying to add JSON object to an array stored within the JAX-RS class itself.
Having trouble getting the updated array out again with a request to `/shop/getBasket` after doing a post to `shop/updateBasket` (in which I added a new element to the array).

The array I get after posting, doing get `/shop/getBasket` seems to not have changed after I've updated it.

What's wrong?

```
@Path("shop")
public class shopServer(){
    JSONArray basket = new JSONArray;

    @POST
    @Path("addToBasket/{itemID}")
    public String updateBasket(@PathParam("itemID") String itemID){
        basket.put(new JSONObject().put("obj",itemID));
        return null;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getBasket")
    public String getBasket(){
        basket.put(new JSONObject().put("obj","asd"));
        return basket.toString();
    }
}
```

calling `/shop/getBasket` in ajax only return the item added within `getBasket()`.

Comment: It's not thread safe. Use a database. If it's just a play-around project, you either need to make the resource class a singleton or  make the field static. By default a new instance of the resource class is created for each requests. Of you want a singleton, you can add `@Singleton` on top of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate requests are getting separate instances of `shopServer` (rename to `ShopServer`, by the way). So `POST addToBasket` gets one instance, and `GET getBasket` gets another. This means you have a new, empty instance of `JSONArray basket` for each request.

There are many ways you can store state. It depends on your needs. You can use a database (try in-memory for development), static variables, singletons.

### See also

- [How does an JAX-RS 'endpoint' behave when making a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044953/how-does-an-jax-rs-endpoint-behave-when-making-a-request)